# Android security app ask for permission when recording audio

Tags: android, audio, permissions, record

When recording audio on android phone.
I already add permission in the manifest file
    
    
I can recording audio on most of the device, but can not recording on some device. The device pop-up window and ask for permission, if I click yes, then I can recording.

I guess this is the security software installed on the phone.

**How can I always get audio recording permission with out user manually click yes.**

Comment: This is not a part of Android.  You would have to identify and research whatever non-standard modification you are encountering.

Comment: I find out that the phone maker has did some modification. They add the security module for each hardware accessing.